# After ajax animation, animation show, but content is not show

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying ajax animation, first time content is animate margin-left:200px, but after animation another content is not loading, any one help me.

This is my code

```
$.ajax({
   url:url,
   beforeSend: function(){
       $('.slide_loader').show();
   },
   success:function(content){
      $('#right_content').animate({                 
            'margin-left' : '200px'
        }, 500);

      $('#right_content').html(content);
      $('.slide_loader').hide();

      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Place them in the `complete` callback for `animate`. Animate is asynch so your `$('#right_content').html(content)` would have got executed before the animate is complete. So use the callback for complete to specify your after animation actions.

```
 success:function(content){
      $('#right_content').animate({                 
            'margin-left' : '200px'
        }, 500,function(){
      $('#right_content').html(content);
      $('.slide_loader').hide();

     });
     return false;
   }
```

[Ref .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Another check you need to make is you are getting `content` as is and no other errors are logged in the console.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of, which might be the source of the unexpected behavior, is that `$.animate` is asynchronous.  That is, the animation won't be done when `$('#right_content').html(content);` is run.  The last argument of `animate` lets you specify a callback function that will run when the animation is done.

ie.

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.slide_loader').show();
    },
    success:function(content){
        $('#right_content').animate({                   
            'margin-left' : '200px'
        }, 500, function() {
          $('#right_content').html(content);
          $('.slide_loader').hide();
        });
    return false;
    }
});
```